# How to "Fill the CPU with OpenMP threads" to run QE-GPU

Tags: quantum-espresso, high-performance-computing, graphical-processing-unit

I am trying to run GPU enabled QE (QE 6.8 running on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-135-generic x86_64) System Configuration: Processor: Intel Xeon Gold 5120 CPU 2.20 GHz (2 Processor) RAM: 96 GB HDD: 6 TB Graphics Card: NVIDIA Quadro P5000 (16 GB))

I am successfully able to run small jobs (with dynamical ram ~1GB). However, when going to even larger systems (less than 16GB), the output abruptly stops during the first iteration(attached below)

```
     Program PWSCF v.6.8 starts on  8Oct2021 at 10:33: 9 

     This program is part of the open-source Quantum ESPRESSO suite
     for quantum simulation of materials; please cite
         "P. Giannozzi et al., J. Phys.:Condens. Matter 21 395502 (2009);
         "P. Giannozzi et al., J. Phys.:Condens. Matter 29 465901 (2017);
         "P. Giannozzi et al., J. Chem. Phys. 152 154105 (2020);
          URL http://www.quantum-espresso.org", 
     in publications or presentations arising from this work. More details at
     http://www.quantum-espresso.org/quote

     Parallel version (MPI & OpenMP), running on     784 processor cores
     Number of MPI processes:                28
     Threads/MPI process:                    28

     MPI processes distributed on     1 nodes
     R & G space division:  proc/nbgrp/npool/nimage =      28
     43440 MiB available memory on the printing compute node when the environment starts
 
     Reading input from 001.in
Warning: card &CELL ignored
Warning: card / ignored

     Current dimensions of program PWSCF are:
     Max number of different atomic species (ntypx) = 10
     Max number of k-points (npk) =  40000
     Max angular momentum in pseudopotentials (lmaxx) =  4
     file Ti.pbe-spn-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.upf: wavefunction(s)  3S 3D renormalized

     gamma-point specific algorithms are used
     Found symmetry operation: I + ( -0.0000 -0.5000  0.0000)
     This is a supercell, fractional translations are disabled

     Subspace diagonalization in iterative solution of the eigenvalue problem:
     a serial algorithm will be used

 
     Parallelization info
     --------------------
     sticks:   dense  smooth     PW     G-vecs:    dense   smooth      PW
     Min         637     232     57                81572    18102    2258
     Max         640     234     60                81588    18118    2266
     Sum       17865    6549   1633              2284245   507201   63345
 
     Using Slab Decomposition
 


     bravais-lattice index     =           14
     lattice parameter (alat)  =      21.0379  a.u.
     unit-cell volume          =    9204.2807 (a.u.)^3
     number of atoms/cell      =           36
     number of atomic types    =            2
     number of electrons       =       288.00
     number of Kohn-Sham states=          173
     kinetic-energy cutoff     =      55.0000  Ry
     charge density cutoff     =     600.0000  Ry
     scf convergence threshold =      1.0E-06
     mixing beta               =       0.4000
     number of iterations used =            8  local-TF  mixing
     energy convergence thresh.=      1.0E-04
     force convergence thresh. =      1.0E-03
     Exchange-correlation= PBE
                           (   1   4   3   4   0   0   0)
     nstep                     =          500


     GPU acceleration is ACTIVE.

     Message from routine print_cuda_info:
     High GPU oversubscription detected. Are you sure this is what you want?

     GPU used by master process:

        Device Number: 0
        Device name: Quadro P5000
        Compute capability : 61
        Ratio of single to double precision performance  : 32
        Memory Clock Rate (KHz): 4513000
        Memory Bus Width (bits): 256
        Peak Memory Bandwidth (GB/s): 288.83

     celldm(1)=  21.037943  celldm(2)=   1.000000  celldm(3)=   2.419041
     celldm(4)=  -0.766650  celldm(5)=  -0.766650  celldm(6)=   0.533303

     crystal axes: (cart. coord. in units of alat)
               a(1) = (   1.000000   0.000000   0.000000 )  
               a(2) = (   0.533303   0.845924   0.000000 )  
               a(3) = (  -1.854558  -1.023161   1.168553 )  

     reciprocal axes: (cart. coord. in units 2 pi/alat)
               b(1) = (  1.000000 -0.630438  1.035056 )  
               b(2) = ( -0.000000  1.182139  1.035056 )  
               b(3) = (  0.000000  0.000000  0.855759 )  


     PseudoPot. # 1 for Ti read from file:
     ../Ti.pbe-spn-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.upf
     MD5 check sum: e281089c08e14b8efcf92e44a67ada65
     Pseudo is Ultrasoft + core correction, Zval = 12.0
     Generated using &quot;atomic&quot; code by A. Dal Corso  v.6.2.2
     Using radial grid of 1177 points,  6 beta functions with: 
                l(1) =   0
                l(2) =   0
                l(3) =   1
                l(4) =   1
                l(5) =   2
                l(6) =   2
     Q(r) pseudized with 0 coefficients 


     PseudoPot. # 2 for O  read from file:
     ../O.pbe-n-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.upf
     MD5 check sum: 91400c9766925bcf19f520983a725ff0
     Pseudo is Ultrasoft + core correction, Zval =  6.0
     Generated using &quot;atomic&quot; code by A. Dal Corso  v.6.3MaX
     Using radial grid of 1095 points,  4 beta functions with: 
                l(1) =   0
                l(2) =   0
                l(3) =   1
                l(4) =   1
     Q(r) pseudized with 0 coefficients 


     atomic species   valence    mass     pseudopotential
        Ti            12.00    47.86700     Ti( 1.00)
        O              6.00    15.99940     O ( 1.00)

     Starting magnetic structure 
     atomic species   magnetization
        Ti           0.200
        O            0.000

     No symmetry found


                                    s                        frac. trans.

      isym =  1     identity                                     

 cryst.   s( 1) = (     1          0          0      )
                  (     0          1          0      )
                  (     0          0          1      )

 cart.    s( 1) = (  1.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000 )
                  (  0.0000000  1.0000000  0.0000000 )
                  (  0.0000000  0.0000000  1.0000000 )


     point group C_1 (1)    
     there are  1 classes
     the character table:

       E    
A      1.00

     the symmetry operations in each class and the name of the first element:

     E        1
          identity                                               

   Cartesian axes

     site n.     atom                  positions (alat units)
         1           O   tau(   1) = (  -0.8353365  -0.5987815   0.7050395  )
         2           Ti  tau(   2) = (  -0.6772809  -0.5115821   0.7050395  )
         3           O   tau(   3) = (  -0.5192254  -0.4243827   0.7050395  )
         4           Ti  tau(   4) = (  -0.9272815  -0.5115821   0.5842738  )
         5           O   tau(   5) = (  -0.7692260  -0.4243827   0.5842738  )
         6           O   tau(   6) = (  -0.3186838  -0.1758181   0.5842738  )
         7           O   tau(   7) = (  -0.4520098  -0.3872999   0.4635080  )
         8           Ti  tau(   8) = (  -0.2939543  -0.3001004   0.4635080  )
         9           O   tau(   9) = (  -0.1358987  -0.2129011   0.4635080  )
        10           O   tau(  10) = (  -0.5686844  -0.1758181   0.7050395  )
        11           Ti  tau(  11) = (  -0.4106289  -0.0886188   0.7050395  )
        12           O   tau(  12) = (  -0.2525734  -0.0014194   0.7050395  )
        13           Ti  tau(  13) = (  -0.6606296  -0.0886188   0.5842738  )
        14           O   tau(  14) = (  -0.5025740  -0.0014194   0.5842738  )
        15           O   tau(  15) = (  -0.0520318   0.2471452   0.5842738  )
        16           O   tau(  16) = (  -0.1853578   0.0356635   0.4635080  )
        17           Ti  tau(  17) = (  -0.0273023   0.1228629   0.4635080  )
        18           O   tau(  18) = (   0.1307533   0.2100623   0.4635080  )
        19           O   tau(  19) = (  -0.3353351  -0.5987815   0.7050395  )
        20           Ti  tau(  20) = (  -0.1772797  -0.5115821   0.7050395  )
        21           O   tau(  21) = (  -0.0192241  -0.4243827   0.7050395  )
        22           Ti  tau(  22) = (  -0.4272803  -0.5115821   0.5842738  )
        23           O   tau(  23) = (  -0.2692247  -0.4243827   0.5842738  )
        24           O   tau(  24) = (   0.1813175  -0.1758181   0.5842738  )
        25           O   tau(  25) = (   0.0479915  -0.3872999   0.4635080  )
        26           Ti  tau(  26) = (   0.2060470  -0.3001004   0.4635080  )
        27           O   tau(  27) = (   0.3641026  -0.2129011   0.4635080  )
        28           O   tau(  28) = (  -0.0686832  -0.1758181   0.7050395  )
        29           Ti  tau(  29) = (   0.0893724  -0.0886188   0.7050395  )
        30           O   tau(  30) = (   0.2474280  -0.0014194   0.7050395  )
        31           Ti  tau(  31) = (  -0.1606282  -0.0886188   0.5842738  )
        32           O   tau(  32) = (  -0.0025728  -0.0014194   0.5842738  )
        33           O   tau(  33) = (   0.4479695   0.2471452   0.5842738  )
        34           O   tau(  34) = (   0.3146435   0.0356635   0.4635080  )
        35           Ti  tau(  35) = (   0.4726991   0.1228629   0.4635080  )
        36           O   tau(  36) = (   0.6307546   0.2100623   0.4635080  )

   Crystallographic axes

     site n.     atom                  positions (cryst. coord.)
         1           O   tau(   1) = (  0.2719137  0.0219125  0.6033439  )
         2           Ti  tau(   2) = (  0.3749954  0.1249943  0.6033439  )
         3           O   tau(   3) = (  0.4780771  0.2280761  0.6033439  )
         4           Ti  tau(   4) = ( -0.0000046 -0.0000050  0.4999975  )
         5           O   tau(   5) = (  0.1030772  0.1030768  0.4999975  )
         6           O   tau(   6) = (  0.3969147  0.3969146  0.4999975  )
         7           O   tau(   7) = (  0.2719156  0.0219145  0.3966511  )
         8           Ti  tau(   8) = (  0.3749973  0.1249964  0.3966511  )
         9           O   tau(   9) = (  0.4780790  0.2280781  0.3966511  )
        10           O   tau(  10) = (  0.2719134  0.5219140  0.6033439  )
        11           Ti  tau(  11) = (  0.3749952  0.6249957  0.6033439  )
        12           O   tau(  12) = (  0.4780769  0.7280775  0.6033439  )
        13           Ti  tau(  13) = ( -0.0000048  0.4999964  0.4999975  )
        14           O   tau(  14) = (  0.1030769  0.6030781  0.4999975  )
        15           O   tau(  15) = (  0.3969145  0.8969160  0.4999975  )
        16           O   tau(  16) = (  0.2719153  0.5219160  0.3966511  )
        17           Ti  tau(  17) = (  0.3749970  0.6249978  0.3966511  )
        18           O   tau(  18) = (  0.4780787  0.7280796  0.3966511  )
        19           O   tau(  19) = (  0.7719150  0.0219125  0.6033439  )
        20           Ti  tau(  20) = (  0.8749966  0.1249943  0.6033439  )
        21           O   tau(  21) = (  0.9780784  0.2280761  0.6033439  )
        22           Ti  tau(  22) = (  0.4999967 -0.0000050  0.4999975  )
        23           O   tau(  23) = (  0.6030784  0.1030768  0.4999975  )
        24           O   tau(  24) = (  0.8969160  0.3969146  0.4999975  )
        25           O   tau(  25) = (  0.7719169  0.0219145  0.3966511  )
        26           Ti  tau(  26) = (  0.8749985  0.1249964  0.3966511  )
        27           O   tau(  27) = (  0.9780803  0.2280781  0.3966511  )
        28           O   tau(  28) = (  0.7719147  0.5219140  0.6033439  )
        29           Ti  tau(  29) = (  0.8749965  0.6249957  0.6033439  )
        30           O   tau(  30) = (  0.9780782  0.7280775  0.6033439  )
        31           Ti  tau(  31) = (  0.4999965  0.4999964  0.4999975  )
        32           O   tau(  32) = (  0.6030782  0.6030781  0.4999975  )
        33           O   tau(  33) = (  0.8969158  0.8969160  0.4999975  )
        34           O   tau(  34) = (  0.7719166  0.5219160  0.3966511  )
        35           Ti  tau(  35) = (  0.8749983  0.6249978  0.3966511  )
        36           O   tau(  36) = (  0.9780801  0.7280796  0.3966511  )

     number of k points=     1  Gaussian smearing, width (Ry)=  0.0100
                       cart. coord. in units 2pi/alat
        k(    1) = (   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000), wk =   1.0000000

                       cryst. coord.
        k(    1) = (   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000), wk =   1.0000000

     Dense  grid:  1142123 G-vectors     FFT dimensions: ( 180, 180, 400)

     Smooth grid:   253601 G-vectors     FFT dimensions: ( 100, 100, 243)

     Dynamical RAM for                 wfc:       2.99 MB

     Dynamical RAM for     wfc (w. buffer):       2.99 MB

     Dynamical RAM for           str. fact:       1.24 MB

     Dynamical RAM for           local pot:       0.00 MB

     Dynamical RAM for          nlocal pot:       7.05 MB

     Dynamical RAM for                qrad:       3.93 MB

     Dynamical RAM for          rho,v,vnew:      25.98 MB

     Dynamical RAM for               rhoin:       8.66 MB

     Dynamical RAM for           G-vectors:       2.40 MB

     Dynamical RAM for          h,s,v(r/c):       2.74 MB

     Dynamical RAM for          <psi|beta>:       0.54 MB

     Dynamical RAM for                 psi:       5.98 MB

     Dynamical RAM for                hpsi:       5.98 MB

     Dynamical RAM for                spsi:       5.98 MB

     Dynamical RAM for      wfcinit/wfcrot:       8.53 MB

     Dynamical RAM for           addusdens:     131.34 MB

     Dynamical RAM for          addusforce:     160.16 MB

     Estimated static dynamical RAM per process >      76.37 MB

     Estimated max dynamical RAM per process >     236.53 MB

     Estimated total dynamical RAM >       6.47 GB

     Check: negative core charge=   -0.000001
     Generating pointlists ...
     new r_m :   0.0722 (alat units)  1.5191 (a.u.) for type    1
     new r_m :   0.0722 (alat units)  1.5191 (a.u.) for type    2

     Initial potential from superposition of free atoms

     starting charge  287.98222, renormalised to  288.00000

     negative rho (up, down):  9.119E-05 6.477E-05
     Starting wfcs are  216 randomized atomic wfcs

     total cpu time spent up to now is       14.0 secs

     Self-consistent Calculation
[tb_dev] Currently allocated     2.23E+01 Mbytes, locked:    0 /   9
[tb_pin] Currently allocated     0.00E+00 Mbytes, locked:    0 /   0

     iteration #  1     ecut=    55.00 Ry     beta= 0.40
     Davidson diagonalization with overlap

---- Real-time Memory Report at c_bands before calling an iterative solver
           980 MiB given to the printing process from OS
             0 MiB allocation reported by mallinfo(arena+hblkhd)
         32000 MiB available memory on the node where the printing process lives
     GPU memory used/free/total (MiB): 11117 / 5152 / 16270
------------------
     ethr =  1.00E-02,  avg # of iterations =  1.5
```

The CRASH file generated says

```
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     task #        24
     from  addusdens_gpu  : error #         1
      cannot allocate aux2_d 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     task #        14
     from  addusdens_gpu  : error #         1
      cannot allocate aux2_d 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     task #         5
     from  addusdens_gpu  : error #         1
      cannot allocate aux2_d 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     task #         7
     from  addusdens_gpu  : error #         1
      cannot allocate aux2_d 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     task #        15
     from  addusdens_gpu  : error #         1
      cannot allocate aux2_d 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     task #        17
     from  addusdens_gpu  : error #         1
      cannot allocate aux2_d 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     task #        10
     from  addusdens_gpu  : error #         1
      cannot allocate aux2_d 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     task #         9
     from  addusdens_gpu  : error #         1
      cannot allocate aux2_d 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     task #        12
     from  addusdens_gpu  : error #         1
      cannot allocate aux2_d 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     task #         4
     from  addusdens_gpu  : error #         1
      cannot allocate aux2_d 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     task #        13
     from  addusdens_gpu  : error #         1
      cannot allocate aux2_d 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     task #        19
     from  addusdens_gpu  : error #         1
      cannot allocate aux2_d 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Using -ndiag 1 and -ntg1 with pw.x also gave a similar output with the following additional lines

```
     negative rho (up, down):  9.119E-05 6.477E-05
     Starting wfcs are  216 randomized atomic wfcs

     total cpu time spent up to now is       11.9 secs

     Self-consistent Calculation
[tb_dev] Currently allocated     3.21E+01 Mbytes, locked:    0 /   9
[tb_pin] Currently allocated     0.00E+00 Mbytes, locked:    0 /   0

     iteration #  1     ecut=    55.00 Ry     beta= 0.40
     Davidson diagonalization with overlap

---- Real-time Memory Report at c_bands before calling an iterative solver
          1036 MiB given to the printing process from OS
             0 MiB allocation reported by mallinfo(arena+hblkhd)
         36041 MiB available memory on the node where the printing process lives
     GPU memory used/free/total (MiB): 8915 / 7354 / 16270
------------------
     ethr =  1.00E-02,  avg # of iterations =  1.5
0: ALLOCATE: 156244752 bytes requested; status = 2(out of memory)
0: ALLOCATE: 156239280 bytes requested; status = 2(out of memory)
0: ALLOCATE: 156239280 bytes requested; status = 2(out of memory)
0: ALLOCATE: 156244752 bytes requested; status = 2(out of memory)
0: ALLOCATE: 156239280 bytes requested; status = 2(out of memory)
0: ALLOCATE: 156239280 bytes requested; status = 2(out of memory)
0: ALLOCATE: 156244752 bytes requested; status = 2(out of memory)
0: ALLOCATE: 156244752 bytes requested; status = 2(out of memory)
0: ALLOCATE: 156244752 bytes requested; status = 2(out of memory)
0: ALLOCATE: 156244752 bytes requested; status = 2(out of memory)
0: ALLOCATE: 156239280 bytes requested; status = 2(out of memory)
0: ALLOCATE: 156239280 bytes requested; status = 2(out of memory)
0: ALLOCATE: 156244752 bytes requested; status = 2(out of memory)
0: ALLOCATE: 156239280 bytes requested; status = 2(out of memory)
0: ALLOCATE: 156244752 bytes requested; status = 2(out of memory)
0: ALLOCATE: 156239280 bytes requested; status = 2(out of memory)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

  Process name: [[58344,1],12]
  Exit code:    127
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I believe I am not "filling the CPUs with OpenMP threads", or running 1 MPI on 1 GPU, as suggested in this [document.](https://gitlab.com/QEF/material-for-ljubljana-qe-summer-school/-/blob/master/Day-5/slides/Hands-on.pdf)

Can someone please give some suggestions? Sorry for the long post. I am totally new to this field. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think this is the case? I don't know QE, but all the error messages say you have run out of memory, and more threads is not going to solve that.

Comment: With no GPU support, it does not stop abruptly, but the calculation is slow. Plus, the document I shared. Because of these 2 reasons, I suspect not 'filling the CPUs'

Comment: I'm not sure what "filling the CPUs with openmp threads" means but that is mentioned in the document you shared as a general suggestion and seems unrelated to the issue you face. As the error message indicates, I think this is a memory issue as suggested by @IanBush.

Comment: That PDF seems to say to use one and only one MPI process per GPU, which you seem not to be doing since you seem to be using 28 MPI processes and only 1 GPU. Can you try again with just 1 MPI process and add to your question the output you get then?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Nike. I too feel the same. Can you please tell me how to run just 1 MPI process on 1 GPU

Comment: Just a note, while you will see all replies to your post, others in the comments will only see them if you ping them like this @NikeDattani

Comment: Thank you @Tyberius. I appreciate it.

Comment: It looks like you're running on a single machine, with a single GPU, so you don't want to use MPI at all. Either run the non-MPI version of QE, or just give "1" as the number of processes to use in MPI. You definitely do *not* want to be running 28 MPI processes, each with 28 OpenMP threads!

Comment: Noted with thanks @PhilHasnip

Comment: How did this go? Have you learned anything new about this over the last 11 months? Perhaps you could write a self-answer which would help future users? Please update us!

Comment: Sure @NikeDattani.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of the PW forum and after digging a bit, I have gained some understanding of what went wrong.

1. My job had

> "way too many processes spanning way too many threads for a single
> node."

(from an answer to my question at [PW forum](https://www.mail-archive.com/users@lists.quantum-espresso.org/msg41170.html))

The suggestion was to first use OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 (turning off OpenMP - MPI coupling; i.e., run job on a single thread), such that the process ran on 1 MPI running on 1 GPU, and then start increasing the threads.

2. From the **[MaX School on QE: Hands-on QE on HPC and GPU systems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMT-9sGXj38)**, I gained a little more insight into how calculations should be run on GPU systems.

Suppose we have 8 cores on the system and 2 GPUs, it is advisable that the number of MPIs and GPUs are kept the same. That is, each MPI process should communicate with a single GPU. Adding more MPI processes to the same number of GPUs (say, each GPU being accessed by 2 or more MPI processes) might enhance the performance but could also give the same performance or even degrade it. So, the best combination of MPIs, and GPUs needs to be figured out for the system to get optimal performance.

Hope this helps.

( I am new to GPU acceleration and MPI-related things. So any more insights by users will be highly appreciated.)